# React Redux Localize only returning first letter

Tags: reactjs, localization, react-redux

I'm attempting to use react redux, but I'm facing an issue. The following code only renders the first letter, "T", rather than all of "Test". The Redux debugger shows all of "Test". How can this be?

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app';
import { localizeReducer } from 'react-localize-redux';
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import { LocalizeProvider } from "react-localize-redux";

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({localize: localizeReducer})
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <LocalizeProvider store={store}>
        <App />
    </LocalizeProvider>,

    document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Translate, withLocalize } from "react-localize-redux";
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.props.initialize({
            languages: [
              { name: "English", code: "en" }
            ],
            options: { renderToStaticMarkup }
        });

        let english = {
            abc: "Test"
        }

        this.props.addTranslation(english);
    }

    render() {
        return <Translate id="abc" />;
    }
}

export default withLocalize(App);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a translation for just one language, you would use [addTranslationForLanguage](https://ryandrewjohnson.github.io/react-localize-redux-docs/#addtranslationforlanguage). This one uses the single language format:

```
let english = {
  abc: "Test"
}

this.props.addTranslationForLanguage(english, 'en');
```

[addTranslation](https://ryandrewjohnson.github.io/react-localize-redux-docs/#addtranslation) should be used when using multiple languages. This api requires the data in [all-language-format](https://ryandrewjohnson.github.io/react-localize-redux-docs/#all-languages-format), so you would do something like this array for multiple languages:

```
let translations = {
  abc: ["Test"]
}

this.props.addTranslationForLanguage(translations);
```

Comment: Thanks - yeah it was quite a silly mistake. Appreciate the quick answer!